# pass method POST using ajax to php in boostrap modal wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Hi guys I am having problem with my ajax passing postID to my modal . var pid gets the id I wanted but when I echo the postID it doesnt get the value from ajax. please help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var pid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: 'domain/modal.php',
           data: 'post_id=' + pid,
           success: function (r) {
          
           }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<a class="link-to-post" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="modal" data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">Button</a>

<?php
$post_ID = $_POST['post_id'];
?>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          <?php echo $post_ID;?> 
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

change `data: 'post_id=' + pid,`

to `data:{ 'post_id': pid },`

add an id in the div where you want to put your id. Something like:

`<div id="idContainer" class="col-sm-6"></div>`

in your success function you could add this

`$('#idContainer').html(pid);`

Comment: Still no value from $_POST['post_id']; :( @miggy

Comment: could you update the code snippet? maybe im missing something.

Comment: I added the button link to trigger the modal and get the ID @miggy

Comment: Ahh so that's what it is. I think it is not possible when clicking the button to display the value using php. From my understanding as an average developer, when the page loads all php codes are already processed. Its like between server side and client side thing. To achieve your end goal i suggest to use success function in the ajax

Comment: is it possible to load onclick first use ajax then show the modal?

Comment: @ChristianRead not sure about that. sorry

Comment: @ChristianRead i updated my answer. mabye its not the best way but it works :)

Comment: Thanks @miggy I tried it but my problem is how can use the ID as variable in PHP? ill use that to get the content in php

Comment: use your ajax for that. the url that you're calling should return data. from there, you should be able to get it.